# Can I convert all files with jquery file upload to jpg?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) script and it's working really well so far.  The last obstacle I have is I only want to use **jpg** images for my website but allow users the option of uploading gif, png, or jpg.

I'm assuming I need to alter or add some additional methods to the upload.class.php file to accomplish this.

Has anyone done this before and if so is this the correct file to modify?

Comment: Just curious, why are you stuck on JPG? You're going to probably degrade with a GIF to JPG conversion, for instance, and PNG is a higher-quality format than JPG. Are you worried about compression?

Comment: Also, you probably want to look at [PHP's image utilities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php). GD, GMagick, and ImageMagick are all image processing tools.

Comment: Size was a concern but I'm starting to think I can eliminate the GIF option and simply convert PNG to JPG.  I have over a hundred thousand images currently and growing. Does it make sense to convert PNG to JPG in this case?

Comment: What's your browsing caching strategy? Does a CDN make sense with so many deliverables? I would guess you might be better off not letting users upload PNGs at all and have them convert them. JPG isn't a lossless compression if you're trying to save space/bandwidth.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter as I could serve either format via the web but we also have android and iOS apps behind the scenes that also need to access these images.

Comment: JPGs will give you the option of a smaller file size, but at a cost of course; automating it may be problematic. I don't know what the reference to Android and iOS is getting at, but if you aggressively cache or use a content delivery network, you could have a better experience if you have the right problem; that won't work in all cases. Nevertheless, that link I have above links to PHP's image utilities, and ImageMagick and GD both have the means to convert between formats. Note, if you're going to do a lot at once or have many to do during the day, you might run an hourly or nightly script.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write some pretty tough conversion functions if you want to implement it in pure JavaScript and you'll be limited to modern browsers that support `FileAPI` and `FileReference`. Also the conversion function you'll have to write would manipulate the files at the binary level and will have to respect some pretty strict file structures as specified by GIF/JPEG/PNG standards specifications.

As i recall `SWFUpload` (a Flash - ActionScript - JavaScript library) has this functionality embedded, you can specify the format in which it should send the file to the server but it only applies if you wish to use the resizing function which sends a resized version of the original file to the server but it has some downsides.

Comment: I think the Javascript/jQuery parts are noise. It's a PHP problem mainly. See the `upload.class.php` reference in the question.

Comment: Yeah I know, I've seen many misguided questions that started out as "how do i do this in javascript" and ended up as "oh this is usually a backend thing... but i'm better at javascript, oh well..."

Comment: But in order to cover more people that might read this answer later on I'm giving a complete answer based on the question. I had to do image processing client-side to avoid server-side memory limits even though the limits were pretty big, it was hard for server configuration to keep up with new high density cameras that sent 12-15mb files which PHP failed to resize while SWFUpload worked like a charm.